# How do I create a 404 page?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

My application catches all url requests with an `@app.route`, but occasionally I bump into a bad url for which I have no matching jinja file (bu it does match an existing `@app.route`). So I want to redirect such requests to a 404 page for that bad url.

How to discriminate between "a jinja file exists" and "a jinja file doesn't exist" before returning `render_template()`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Jinja will throw an exception if the template is not found: `TemplateNotFound`

So instead of:

```
def myview():
    return render_template(...)
```

you could do something like this:

```
def myview():
    try:
        return render_template(...)
    except TemplateNotFound:
        abort(404)
```

And then handle the 404 error with a custom error page as explained in the [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/errorpages/#error-handlers). Don't forget to import `abort` from `flask` and `TemplateNotFound` from `jinja2`

Comment: Yahoo! you are right render_template() really returned Exception if jinja file not found. It works. thank you for your cool answer.

Comment: Add  to your answer following code please. 'from flask import abort'