# Avoiding repetition with Flask - but is it too DRY?

Tags: security, flask, dry

Let us assume I serve data to colleagues in-office with a small Flask app, and let us also assume that it is a project I am not explicitly 'paid to do' so I don't have all the time in the world to write code.

It has occurred to me in my experimentation with pet projects at home that instead of decorating every last route with `@app.route('/some/local/page')` that I can do the following:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, abort
from collections import OrderedDict

goodURLS = OrderedDict([('/index','Home'),    ##can be passed to the template
        ('/about', 'About'),      ##to create the navigation bar
        ('/foo', 'Foo'),
        ('/bar', 'Bar'),          ##hence the use of OrderedDict
        ('/eggs', 'Eggs'),        ##to have a set order for that navibar
        ('/spam', 'Spam')])

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<destination>')
def goThere(destination):
    availableRoutes = goodURLS.keys():
    if "/" + destination in availableRoutes:
        return render_template('/%s.html' % destination, goodURLS=goodURLS)
else:
    abort(404)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def notFound(e):
    return render_template('/notFound.html'), 404
```

Now all I need to do is update my one list, and both my navigation bar and route handling function are lock-step.

Alternatively, I've written a method to determine the viable file locations by using `os.walk` in conjunction with `file.endswith('.aGivenFileExtension')` to locate every file which I mean to make accessible.  The user's request can then be compared against the list this function returns (which obviously changes the `serveTheUser()` function.

```
from os import path, walk

def fileFinder(directory, extension=".html"):
    """Returns a list of files with a given file extension at a given path.
    By default .html files are returned.
    """
    foundFilesList = []
    if path.exists(directory):
        for p, d, files in walk(directory):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith(extension):
                    foundFilesList.append(file)
    return foundFilesList

goodRoutes = fileFinder('./templates/someFolderWithGoodRoutes/')
```

The question is, Is This Bad?

There are many aspects of Flask I'm just not using (mainly because I haven't needed to know about them yet) - so maybe this is actually limiting, or redundant when compared against a built-in feature of Flask.  Does my lack of explicitly decorating each route rob me of a great feature of Flask?

Additionally, is either of these methods more or less safe than the other?  I really don't know much about web security - and like I said, right now this is all in-office stuff, the security of my data is assured by our IT professional and there are no incoming requests from outside the office - but in a real-world setting, would either of these be detrimental? In particular, if I am using the backend to `os.walk` a location on the server's local disk, I'm not asking to have it abused by some ne'er-do-well am I?

EDIT: I've offered this as a bounty, because if it is not a safe or constructive practice I'd like to avoid using it for things that I'd want to like push to Heroku or just in general publicly serve for family, etc. It just seems like decorating every viable route with `app.route` is a waste of time.

Comment: Whether your (working) code sample is "bad", "constructive" or "secure" is going to be subjective (even the "secure" part could depend on other parts of your system) Since your code already works and you're just looking for another's opinion on it, you should instead ask this question at the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: So noted. I'll not be re-asking since the last time I did so, both threads were closed with a "don't double post" warning.  Apparently it isn't better to ask forgiveness than permission after all - get it right the first time. Sheesh, thanks Python :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything really wrong with your solution, in my opinion. The problem is that with this kind of setup the things you can do are pretty limited.

I'm not sure if you simplified your code to show here, but if all you are doing in your view function is to gather some data and then select one of a few templates to render it then you might as well render the whole thing in a single page and maybe use a Javascript tab control to divide it up in sections on the client.

If each template requires different data, then the logic that obtains and processes the data for each template will have to be in your view function, and that is going to look pretty messy because you'll have a long chain of if statements to handle each template. Between that and separate view functions per template I think the latter will be quicker, even more so if you also consider the maintenance effort.

**Update**: based on the conversion in the comments I stand by my answer, with some minor reservations.

I think your solution works and has no major problems. I don't see a security risk because you are validating the input that comes from the client before you use it.

You are just using Flask to serve files that can be considered static if you ignore the navigation bar at the top. You should consider compiling the Flask app into a set of static files using an extension like Frozen-Flask, then you just host the compiled files with a regular web server. And when you need to add/remove routes you can modify the Flask app and compile it again.

Another thought is that your Flask app structure will not scale well if you need to add server-side logic. Right now you don't have any logic in the server, everything is handled by jQuery in the browser, so having a single view function works just fine. If at some point you need to add server logic for these pages then you will find that this structure isn't convenient.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not positive I follow, but I will try to explain. Essentially I am serving what I think would properly be referred to as single page apps which reference unique JSON files for different data, and then I use jQuery to give the different pages their correct functionality. There is some "shared" functionality in the base template - links to shared CSS so there's a uniform appearance, a jQuery script for a dialog box, typical Jinja navi bar, etc. I then use templates to fill in the `main` div in my base template with the app in question. More or less. :) Does this inform your answer?

Comment: Do you have to pass any additional data to your templates, besides the list of URLs for the navbar? If yes, is this data the same or different for each of the templates?

Comment: Well each template uses a different JSON file, which right now is loaded with a jQuery call (it could probably be a template thing where I iterate over entries, but the jQuery was written before Flask entered into the mix, and It Works Fine). The apps do work with different data in fairly small but separate JSON files - else they would not be separate apps.

Answer (score 0):

I assume based on your code that all the routes have a corresponding template file of the same name (destination to destination.html) and that the goodURL menu bar is changed manually.  An easier method would be to try to render the template at request and return your 404 page if it doesn't exist.

```
from jinja2 import TemplateNotFound
from werkzeug import secure_filename

....

@app.route('/<destination>')
def goThere(destination):
    destTemplate = secure_filename("%s.html" % destination)
    try:
        return render_template(destTemplate, goodURLS=goodURLS)
    except TemplateNotFound:
        abort(404)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def notFound(e):
    return render_template('/notFound.html'), 404
```

This is adapted from the answer to [Stackoverflow: How do I create a 404 page?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10995088/2685415).

Edit: Updated to make use of Werkzeug's [`secure_filename`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/utils/#werkzeug.utils.secure_filename) to clean user input.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you did there, but I think that comparing it against some kind of list of valid links is strictly better - if for no other reason than, let's say I have .html files sitting there that I do NOT want to serve (maybe they're under construction, or maybe the client-facing app should just never go there, or maybe other reasons I can't think of but would be no less valid). So eventually I would want that explicitly declared anyway. I know Flask CAN return files that aren't explicitly set using the `@app.route` decorator -- one goal is to maintain control over that process though

Comment: @Stick - In that case, how do you keep incomplete .html files out of the list created by `fileFinder()`?  It should include every .html file in the directory, including those that you potentially don't want viewable.  Personally, I don't see any security issues with how you are implementing it, though I speak from the perspective of serving it from behind Nginx with Gunicorn, not Heroku. Out of curiosity, how do you get the generated list to the view, as it wasn't apparent from the code provided?

Comment: Let all the "auto-exported" templates start with a prefix, e.g. public_about.html, public_foo.html. Then you do destTemplate = "public_%s.html" % destination. That way a user cannot accidentally get an internal template back, and in your template folder you see immediately what is auto-exported. HOWEVER, you should also make sure that only allowed characters are in destination, e.g. via a regular expression.

Comment: @Seberius - the second method is an alternative to the first, and it can have the same problems. It uses `file.endswith('.html')` to ensure that I'm not just serving any old file. However the first code example is the one I'm actually using at present - the fileFinder is just a theoretical alternative. Also the `goodURLS` dict is passed in turning `render_template`: that's what `goodURLS=goodURLS` does. This was a lift from the Jinja docs. The template then iterates over the key/value pairs and generates a navibar based on that info.

Comment: @HolgerSchurig - I do this already by making sure that my template files have a different file extension. So in this way, requests that are somehow pointed at a file with a different extension shouldn't be valid.